# How functions create new functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the Eloquent Javascript book I came across this code.
I understood how this works and the passing of arguments but what I am unable to understand is author's statement regarding this code that it's a function which can create another function!

My question is: How is it creating a new function? What is happening which the author is calling creation of a new function? I mean sure we are creating a function called greaterThan and it has another function in it but I can't see how greaterThan is creating another function!

I assure you I have read many similar Qs before asking but couldn't find the answer I am looking for. Thank you for your time & help.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) {
    return m > n;
  };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

Comment: In JS, functions are first class citizens. They behave just like any object. You can create them wherever you want, pass them as arguments, return them, etc. Not sure what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: I understand that they can be created and passed as arguments, what I don't get it is how this function is creating another function! @Oriol

Comment: @CEOUnderworld: Every function is an object in JS. Every function definition evaluates to such a function. Call `greaterThan(…)` twice and it will return two different functions.

Comment: @CEOUnderworld You have a function expression in your code (see [Function Definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13)). That creates a function according to [Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)

Comment: @CEOUnderworld: Note that the function *returns* a function.  It doesn't actually calculate anything, it returns something that calculates something.  That function is then assigned to a variable (`greaterThan10`) which *itself* is invoked to perform the calculation.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/ or http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/5933-what-exactly-is-a-first-class-function-and-why-you-should-care.html

Comment: I don't understand this question, but it doesn't seem a duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for me.

Answer (score 1):

The function is being created on the sixth line.

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

This creates a function `greaterThan10` which can be used to check if numbers are greater than 10. You can see it used on line 7.

Edit:
When the function `greaterThan` is called on line 6, it returns the nested function, effectively making

```
greaterThan10 = function(m){
    return m > 10;
};
```

The author was calling `greaterThan10` a 'new function' created by the function `greaterThan`.

Comment: One might argue that the function is created in line 2 (to 4). Sure, it's returned from `greaterThan()` and assigned to a variable in line 6, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Fine. It is created on line 2 and assigned to a variable on line 6. I don't think this is an important distinction to CEO Underworld.

Comment: Let me try to understand, function(m) is written in line 2 but on the time of writing it was not created, when the greaterThan function runs then only it creates function(m) and that means whenever a function is written 'in' a function the former can be called creating the latter! Pardon me if all that was wrong and please correct me.

Comment: That is correct. When a function is written the way it is on line 2 (not assigned to a variable), it is called an anonymous function. On line 6, the `greaterThan` function is called. It returns our anonymous function, which remembers `n` passed to `greaterThan`. So `greaterThan10` is effectively equal to `function(m){ return m > 10; };`

Comment: Thank you for the help @Marcel

Comment: Anytime @CEOUnderworld